# Calling a batch file with a string variable as a parameter only shows first word of string

Tags: command-line, batch

I'm trying to call a batch file while sending a string variable, but when i try to get it it only shows the first word of the string.

before calling the other program i echo it to check if it is defined and i see the whole sentence (first file):

```
set /p input=
echo %input%
call test.bat %input%
```

but when i try to get it (second file):

```
set output=%1
echo %output%
```

it only shows the first word.

What do i need to do to get the whole sentence from one batch file to another using a call command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is simple.

When you work with a batchfile, every parameter is accessed through %1, %2, %3... up to 9 parameters.

Parameters are separated by a space, so if you enter more words and separate them with a space, in essence, they become multiple parameters. The solution is simple though, put the %input% inside quotes to make the batchfile understand it is supposed to be one parameter. Your script becomes:

```bat
set /p input=
echo %input%
call test.bat "%input%"
```

Answer (score 1):

If the input contains spaces you have to enter it using quotes to let the batch capture the whole parameter as one, containing spaces.

Now, in the second batch, you only have to add the `~` symbol to the parameter like this:

```
REM Note the use of ~ after the percentage symbol

set output=%~1
echo %output%
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution from LPChip sounds good and if you want to remove the quotes, have a look at this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/379779/4828335